# C - 2 arrays, check if one is a sub array and return index

Tags: arrays, c, size, dimensional

i have a task to write a function that will get 2 arrays and their size:

```
int contain(int big[], int size_b, int small[], int size_s)
```

the program should check if the small array is a sub array of the big array, if true should return the Index number of the first number in the small array, else return -1.

Example:
2 4 61 5 8 5 56 89 3 -2

5 56 89 3 -2

function should return 5.

9 5 12 7 8 -2 4 32 900 13

9 5 12 8 7

function should return -1.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: im new to coding so im pretty much stuck from the start, watching videos on how i should approach this question

Comment: First do a sanity check of the parameters, returning `-1` if size_b <= 0, size_s <= 0, or size_b < size_s. Then do an outer loop from 0 to less than size_b - size_s, and an inner loop from 0 to less than size_s, comparing elements of big[] and small[], breaking out early if there is a mismatch. If you get all the way through the inner loop without breaking out early, then you have found the small array in the large array and can return the current index of the outer loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the comments to see the explanations

```
int contain(int big[], int size_b, int small[], int size_s) {
    int contains, k;
    for(int i = 0; i < size_b; i++){
        // assume that the big array contains the small array
        contains = 1;
        // check if the element at index i in the big array is the same as 
        // the first element in the small array
       if(big[i] == small[0]){
           // if yes, then we start form k = 1, because we already know that
           // the first element in the small array is the same as the element 
           // at index i in the big array
           k = 1;
           // we start to check if the next elements in the big array
           // are the same as the elements in the small array
           // (we start from i+1 position because we already know that the element 
           // at the position i is the same as the first element in the small array)
           for(int j = i + 1; j < size_b; j++){
               // range for k must be from 1 to size_s-1
               // if we reached the end of the small array or if the small 
               // array contains only one element then break the for loop
               if(k >= size_s - 1) {
                   break;
               }
               // if the element at the position j in the big array is different
               // from the element at the position k in the small array then we
               // flag that we did not find the sequence we were looking for (contains=0)
               if(big[j] != small[k]){
                   contains = 0;
                   break;
               }
               // increment k because we want the next element in the small array
               k++;
           }
           // if contains flag is not 0 that means we found the sequence we were looking
           // for and that sequence starts from index i in the big array
           if(contains) {
               return i;
           }
       }
    }
    // if the sequence we were looking for was not found
    // then -1 is returned
    return -1;
}
```

Here is the code without comments

```
int contain(int big[], int size_b, int small[], int size_s) {
    int contains, k;
    for(int i = 0; i < size_b; i++){
        contains = 1;
       if(big[i] == small[0]){
           k = 1;
           for(int j = i + 1; j < size_b; j++){
               if(k >= size_s - 1) {
                   break;
               }
               if(big[j] != small[k]){
                   contains = 0;
                   break;
               }
               k++;
           }
           if(contains) {
               return i;
           }
       }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: First for-loop could be made to iterate (size_b - size_s) times to save unnecessary iterations at the end.

Comment: "First for-loop could be made to iterate (size_b - size_s) times to save unnecessary iterations at the end."

In this case will not find if small array is exactly on the end of big array, have just tested.
Proper way is: (size_b - size_s +1). So, first loop shall be: 
for(int i = 0; i < (size_b-size_s + 1); i++)